# Two different websites in one remote hosting

Tags: htaccess, redirects

My client asked me that a website that is hosted in one server (and pointing there through a domain) should also be accessed (into a specific directory) from another domain, which is not pointing there. For example:

http://www.foo.com, hosted at GoDaddy, with the full website

http://www.bar.com, hosted at Bluehost, needs to access http://www.foo.com/bar, as if it was the http://www.bar.com's root.

So, if anybody enters through http://www.bar.com, it should internally load http://www.foo.com/bar, without visually changing the url.

I amb not sure if this is possible using .htaccess or anything like this. Could anybody show me some light? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !bar.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/bar/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I found this in [an article](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/migrate-domains/) by searching for "rewrite all calls to other domain htacces".